# Use first isomorphism theorem to prove that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $(G/K)/(H/K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that $G/H$  is isomorphic to $(G/K)/(H/K)$ where
>   H and K are normal subgroups of G, K is subgroup of H.

I know how to prove it conversely, but I am not sure how to prove this one.
Can I map $f \colon  G \rightarrow (G/K)/(H/K)$ where $f(g) = ghK$?

We need to use the first isomorphism theorem. 
I am not sure, but then how can show what is the kernel?

Comment: The title is fine, but in the body of the Question you should carefully introduce the objects labelled $G,H,K$ with any assumptions given to support the claim.  For example, $G$ is a group and $H,K$ are (normal?) subgroups of $G$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As I see, you needed just to consider the map $$f: G/K\to G/H$$ suuch that $(gK)\to gH$.indeed, $f$ is a well definied function and it is an homomrphism. Can you see what is its Kernel?

Comment: Thank u, but we have to use first isomorphic theorem

Comment: Yes. Infact, after showing that $f$ is a homomorphism then you think about its kernel and finally use the first isomrphic theorem. Indeed, the kernel is $H/K$

Comment: Thank you, but it asks to show G/H ~ (G/K)/(H/K) . But your way is (G/K)/(H/K)～G/H. Is it ok to converse the isomorphism? If do not converse it, can we still map it?

Comment: It is not a 'if-then' statement so you don't need converse. That is if $A$ is isomorphic to $B$ then $B$ is also isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: @YongZhao: See the wise comment of Vikrant.